# How to identify Contact/Business type from the Customer datatype in CRM 365?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I have created 'Customer' datatype in one of our custom entity. From there if I try to query to find whether the customer is of contact/Account
by using the following query,

[image]

```
   SELECT customer FROM entityname
            INNER JOIN contact ON ContactId=contact_account_customer
```

I am getting error saying invalid column name. I would like to know whether the relationship name to contact and account is useful to find
whether customer is contact or account. If not whats the use of this relationship name?

Comment: Are you sure you typed correct schema name? Invalid column name is clear error message of wrong/unavailable table columns..

Comment: Yes I did. Even I tried Select * from contact_account_customer thinking it as table like (N:N) relation table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Entity Name: new_promotionaloffer
Attribute Name: new_luckycustomer

```
SELECT new_luckycustomer FROM new_promotionaloffer E
LEFT JOIN Contact C ON C.ContactId = E.new_contact_new_promotionaloffer_LuckyCustomer
LEFT JOIN Account A ON A.AccountId = E.new_account_new_promotionaloffer_LuckyCustomer
```

[image]